# When app crashes socket.io object gets recreated and the app gets offline

Tags: android, socket.io

I am using socket.io to make presence in a video chat application in Android. The user first login, once that succeeds I connect the client side(the application) with the socket in the LoginActivity then I finish() the LoginActivity(which is the only place I connect with the socket at) then I take the user to the HomeActivity.

The socket object is in the application scope so that I can keep the user online as long as he/she is using the application(the connect action happens in the LoginActivity but the socket by which I connect is in the ApplicationClass), so far so good.

THE PROBLEM:

If for any reason the application crashes in Android 8 and above the application will go back a step as I understand(if I am wrong, please tell me) for example if I am in the 1-HomeActivity then I go to the 2-SettingsActivity then 3-UpdateProfile, and the application crashes at UpdateProfile the application will not crash totally, but it will go to the 2-SettingsActivity BUT(and here comes the problem) all objects in the whole application those are alive get recreated which means the socket I mentioned earlier will get recreated and the older one will be killed and the client will be offline.

The only solution I got is to reconnect with socket but I am already loggedIn (there is no way to go to the place where socket.connect() takes place which is the LoginActivity as I mentioned) and there is nothing to tell me (callback or listener) that the application crashed so that I can say: "Ah when crash execute this code and do the connect() action".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In my video chat App, I have a 'Global Timer' that runs every second, and in this timer function:

1. I send a heartbeat to server every 10 seconds.
2. On the server side, I have an array to record all connected users, I'll remove a user from this array if NO heartbeat received in 30 seconds, and I also disconnect this socket id from server side.
3. the login id is sent with the heartbeat function, to 'refresh' the login status of the user, in case a connection was lost and recreated.
4. on receiving heartbeat, the server send a heartbeatreturn back to the client.
5. on receiving heartbeatreturn, the client do some scheduled jobs (Some jobs can only be done with online connection)

I do know that socket.io has its own heartbeat, but the socket.io heartbeat does not always work! especially when you use socket.io to send large video file.